# shinyapps.io doesn't support tensorflow 1

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, reticulate, tensorflow1.15

I am using the reticulate package to run TensorFlow 1.15 in the R code. I also created my same code on shiny app. When I try to deploy and share it through shinyapps.io, i got the error below.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.14.0

What do you suggest to me? How can I share it or how can I fix this error?

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing you can do here. If that's not R package, like system dependency or package from other languages, you get to ask Rstudio guys to add them for you. Let me know if you find any other sulotion.